# Do Distant Worlds AI Players Have The Same Restrictions As The Human Player?

Tags: distant-worlds-shadows

Do the AI players in Distant Worlds have the same restrictions as the human player when it comes to colony expansion? Specifically the `Colony Influence` Range and `Colonization Range Limits` setup on this screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the AI has to adhere to the same rules as the player when establishing new colonies.

Lowering the colonization range section will lead to empires which have their colonies more clustered.